# Shell: SVN status pipe to php to check syntax

Tags: php, svn, bash, shell, pipe

I know this is simple but I just cant figure it out.

I have a bunch of files output by "svn st" that I want php to do a syntax check on the command line.

This outputs the list of files: svn st | awk '{print $2}'

And this checks a php script: php -l somefile.php

But this, or variants of, doesn't work: svn st | php -l '{print $2}'

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use xargs:

```
 svn st | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L 1 php -l
```

The `xargs -L 1` command reads items from standard input, one per line, and runs the given command for each item separately.  See the xargs(1) man page for more info.